# Can not get mysql-connector-python to install in virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09. I've install virtualenv and after activation then I run pip install mysql-connector-python, but when I run my app I get an error: `ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`. Has anyone else had trouble doing this? I can install it outside of virtualenv and my script runs without issues. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: 2.6.9 (unknown, Oct 29 2013, 19:58:13) [GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)]

Comment: I was able to run my app inside of my venv by installing the python connector outside of virtualenv and then manually copying what was installed in the site-packages folder into my virtual environments site-packages folder. This is no solution however as it defeats the purpose of virtualenv. It's interesting that pip didn't already do this.

Comment: Yeah, this is a hassle since `yum` relies on Python 2.6.x. I would recommend setting up a `virtualenv` with 2.7, that way you get the best of both worlds. [Here](http://tumblr.kurttheviking.com/post/30920138314/painless-python-2-7-on-aws-ec2) is a blog describing the process.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029672/unable-to-find-protobuf-include-directory

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Several things.  There is an inconsistency in package naming so you may want to do:

```
pip search mysql-connector
```

to find out what it is called on your platform. I got two results `mysql-connector-python` and `mysql-connector-repackaged`.

so try this first:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

this may additionally give an error like this:

```
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use 
    --allow-external mysql-connector-python to allow).
```

so finally this should do the job:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: I had to move on in my project, but I will make an effort to test this out and get back to you. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `mysql-connector-python` comes before `--allow-external` **and after**!!

Comment: It looks like --allow-external is not supported in some versions of pip? I'm using pip 1.3.1 in a python 2.7.10 venv and get "no such option: --allow-external"

Comment: Follow-up: I also updated pip to 8.0.2 and get the same result, no such option! But I know this worked before, under python 2.7.8.

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python

Comment: This no longer works. Apparently, allow-external is deprecated

Comment: Answer by @slim worked for me.  sudo easy_install mysql-connector

Answer (score 31):

Solution I found:

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

If you see this error: `option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized`, try this:

```
sudo pip install --egg mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Answer (score 19):

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Can you tell us what environment you're running?

Comment: @slim I tried to install mql.connector in my linux machine, and this worked for me.

Comment: What distro and version?

Comment: This worked for me also (it installed successfully, haven't tried to use it yet), using Windows 10, Python 3.6.4, and pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the similar issue. My env details -
Python 2.7.11
pip 9.0.1
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)

Error on python interpreter  -

```
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
>>>
```

Use pip to search the available module  -

```
$ pip search mysql-connector | grep --color mysql-connector-python



mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2)        - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python (2.0.4)           - MySQL driver written in Python
```

Install the mysql-connector-python-rf -

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Verify

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Apr 26 2016, 13:18:56)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between the two packages? What's does the "-rf" stand for?

Comment: @slim TBH even I am having the same question! could not find the answer yet.. For sure its not something random fancy stuff =)

Comment: mysql-connector-python-random-fix ;)

Comment: @slim see ["What are the differences..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34168651/673991). Summarizing, (1) it's Required For Django 1.8, (2) it's Retrieved the most Frequently, (3) it's the veRsion that actually Functions.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add that

```
sudo easy_install mysql-connector
```

worked for me after pip kept crashing no matter what I did.

Comment: That was the only one that worked for me on quite outdated EC2 instance

Comment: Work with Python3.6 on a Ubuntu 64bit 18.04 as well. Interesting

Comment: Chiming in to add this worked for me using a Python3.7 conda environment, none of the other solutions worked on my end...

Answer (score 5):

I've battled with this and tried upgrading pip and setuptools but actually it seems all you need to do is:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
```

Once you've upgraded virtualenv, create a new virtual environment, activate it and try installing with:

```
pip install https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz
```

(you might need to update the url, but that's the current one)

Answer (score 5):

Command

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

worked for me in my pyenv python version 2.7.12 and pip version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to overcome this problem by entering `mysql-connector-python` package URL, taken from MySQL page, directly to the requirements file, instead of dependency name.

My requirements file looks like this:

```
bson==0.4.2
https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.tar.gz
pymongo==3.2.1
```

After creating virtualenv and switching into it I am executing

```
$ pip install -r ./requirements
```

And pip is doing the rest of the work, i.e., downloading, extracting and installing.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me!

```sh
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

If you get the error, install the latest version of `setuptools` and `wheel`:

```sh
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel
```

Answer (score 3):

Also something that can go wrong: Don't name your own module `mysql`

`import mysql.connector` will fail because the import gives the module in the project precedence over site packages and yours likely doesnt have a `connector.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558741/3416150). Though i meant it for Python3, u can just modify the command python3->python to make it work for python2

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and *none of the solutions below worked*. Some was already installed and *the last one returned me an error*:

```
    pip install mysql-connector
    pip install mysql-connector-python
    pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

**It looks like all I had to do was run the code in a different *IDLE* version**, moving from 3.6 to 3.7.
Before doing that, I also used the windows repair installation tool in two different python versions I have installed.

Sometimes the simplest solutions work. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've installed the mysql connector from within the venv. 
In VSCode, what worked for me is I selected the venv interpreter as the python interpreter.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: An answer is a direct response that sincerely attempts to provide the information/analysis requested by the question. Hence remember link is not an answer.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add some more text and examples or code that someone can use to solve the problem asked in the OP post.

Answer (score 0):

You can download official connector from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) -

Choose `Platform independent` version.

Unzip and cd to the folder.

run `sudo -H python3 setup.py install` from your environment.

Done