# What are the differences between mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector-python-rf and mysql-connector-repackaged?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pip, mysql-connector-python

I'd like to use the `mysql-connector` library for python 3. I could use `pymysql` instead, but `mysql-connector` already has a connection pool implementation, while `pymysql` doesn't seem to have one. So this would be less code for me to write.

However, when I do

```
$ pip3 search mysql-connector
```

I find that these 3 libraries are available:

```
mysql-connector-repackaged     - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python-rf      - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python         - MySQL driver written in Python
```

This is very confusing. Anybody knows which one I should use and why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: pipreqs got it all wrong. https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/261

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was just asking myself similar question and I think I found the "fresh" answer.
Here is info from two weeks ago:
https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/5537

It seems that currently a long-inactive person is owner of the mysql-connector name, hence MySQL developers release under name mysql-connector-python.

Comment: That seems to finally answer the question indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Now mysql-connector description says _Deprecated, go for official version https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python._

Answer (score 21):

The main differences between them are:

- mysql-connector-repackaged: is old, do not use it
- mysql-connector-python 2.0.4: is the original uploaded by MySQL. But it has the problem that does not works with Django >= 1.8. MySQL did not upload yet their stable version 2.1.3 to this repo.
- mysql-connector-python-rf 2.1.3: is the solution to all your problems if you use Django >= 1.8

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have a source about this?

Comment: My own experience @JohnSmithOptional !

Comment: Would recommend using `mysql-connector-python` now, it's on version 8.0.29 as of today.

Answer (score 5):

If I were to base my assessment on the goodness of a package by how many people have downloaded it, I would suggest you choose mysql-connector-python-rf 2.1.3.

- mysql-connector-repackaged 0.3.1 was uploaded in 2012 and had 406 downloads last month (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-repackaged)
- mysql-connector-python-rf 2.1.3 was uploaded in 2015 and had 1416 downloads in the last month (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python-rf)
- mysql-connector-python 2.0.4 has only had 5 downloads in the past month, but that seems to be because it is the official one from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

mysql-connector-python-rf worked for me with pip whereas mysql-connector-python gave me issues.

Comment: The stats must be wrong. Even very obscure libraries have more hits than 5 downloads a month. I guess the stats are wrong because mysql-connector-python is externally hosted (you have to install it using --allow-external).

Comment: the 5 downloads in the past month is seemingly because everyone downloads it straight from dev.mysql.com instead of from pypi

Comment: Just want to callout that `mysql-connector-python` has been more active than the old `rf` package in the last 6-9ish months. It's on version 8.0.11 now (and I believe it's now the more preferred) but :shrugs:.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `mysql-connector-python` nowadays, it's the official release from Oracle and still gets updated.

```
mysql-connector-repackaged     - last updated: Mar 11, 2012 (version 0.3.1)
mysql-connector-python-rf      - last updated: Feb 4, 2017 (version 2.2.2)
mysql-connector-python         - last updated: Dec 7, 2021 (version 8.0.28)
```