# Installing mysql-connector-python for Python 3.4 on cloud

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu, mysql-connector-python

I have a cloud server with Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm having trouble to install the mysql-connector-python on it..

On windows, I used a installer .msi and it works fine, but on the server I already tried using

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

and `pip3 install` all the possibles downloads of https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ for Ubuntu 14.04

no success..

any ideas?

Comment: What does it show when you try the method you mentioned? Have you tried doing `sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python`?

Comment: @AMagoon here's the error, and yes..using sudo(actually it alrealdy is on root) root@maptec-srv01:/home/maptec# sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python-cext-py3_2.1.3-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
Downloading/unpacking mysql-connector-python-cext-py3-2.1.3-1ubuntu14.04-amd64.deb
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python-cext-py3-2.1.3-1ubuntu14.04-amd64.deb
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for mysql-connector-python-cext-py3-2.1.3-1ubuntu14.04-amd64.deb
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log , and it's the same with all 6

Comment: You may have the name wrong. Try doing `pip3 search mysql-connector` to see what's available. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100757/can-not-get-mysql-connector-python-to-install-in-virtualenv) for more info.

Comment: it's weird @AMagoon , I did what you said, I got mysql-connector-python-rf, MySQL-python, MySQL-python-embedded, mysql-connector-repackaged, mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector, and others, but when I try to `pip3 install ...` , with the mysql-connector-python , it gets the same mssage as the same..but with the repackaged works, it worked now for the mysql-connector , thanks