# Unable to find Protobuf include directory during install mysql-connector over pip

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I pulled `mysql-connector-python` code and when I run `python ./setup.py build` I get the following error:

```
Unable to find Protobuf include directory.
```

`pip install Protobuf` was useless

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I also had a same error message when I tried to install mysql-connector 2.2.3 (not mysql-connector-python) by pip.  2.2.3 is development release.
And I could install 2.1.4. How about trying another version?

Answer (score 108):

I found that this error occurs since version 2.2.3.
You can avoid this issue using version 2.1.6.

`pip install mysql-connector==2.1.6`

try above.

Answer (score 12):

As of 2.2.3, Connector/Python uses a C++ extension that interfaces with a MySQL server with the X plugin enabled, using Protobuf as data interchange format.

So, you need to set up where Protobuf is installed on your system (the library, include and protoc binary paths).

**Requirements**

- A C/C++ compiler, such as gcc
- Protobuf C++ (version >= 2.6.0)
- Python development files

**Installation**

You have two options when using pip + pypi:

1) Set environment variables for `MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR`, `MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_LIB_DIR` and `MYSQLXPB_PROTOC`.

2) Add `--install-option` to set these options when using pip:

```
shell> python install mysql-connector --install-option='--with-protobuf-include-dir=<path>' --install-option='--with-protobuf-lib-dir=<path>' --install-option='--with-protoc=<path>'
```

**Important:** Keep in mind that 2.2.3 is a development release.

Answer (score 9):

I also have this issue on my Ubuntu 16.04 and finally can install mysql-connector 2.2.3 with the following steps:

1. Install these packages via the Ubuntu package manager:

   ```
   sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
   ```
2. Set these environment variables:

   ```
   export MYSQLXPB_PROTOC=/usr/bin/protoc
   export MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/google/protobuf
   export MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
   ```
3. Install the mysql-connector package via the Python package manager:

   ```
   pip install mysql-connector
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: also make sure you have gcc-4.9 installed (it's hardcoded in the wheel)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I noticed that `pip install mysql-connector` tried to install v2.2.3, which we don't want. Therefore, I specifically entered `pip install mysql-connector==2.1.6` and it installed without error. Please note too that I am using a virtualenv running python 3.6.1. I installed it there. Here is documentation on installing specific python modules that helped me. https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I am on **WIN 7 64-bit**, python 27. This command works for me and seems most appropriate, particularly when **v2.2.3** is a development version.

```
pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

To install protobuf with mac ports, I did the following

Installing protobuf:

`port install protobuf-cpp`

Declare where is protobuf

`export MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_LIB_DIR=/opt/local/lib
export MYSQLXPB_PROTOC=/opt/local/bin/protoc
export MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/local/include`

Installing the connector

`pip install mysql-connector`

Answer (score 0):

Please know that 2.1.6 Connector fails with `NoneType` error when connecting to Django 1.11. Fixed in 2.1.7.

Read: [mysql-connector-python fails to work with django 1.11](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86105).

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, if you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install protobuf
$ export MYSQLXPB_PROTOC=/usr/local/opt/protobuf/bin/protoc
$ export MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/protobuf/include/
$ export MYSQLXPB_PROTOBUF_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/
$ pip3 install mysql-connector
```