# Pip fails installtions macOs Sierra

Tags: python, pip, macos-sierra

I'm a begginer with Python since I've never used it seriously but just to do some simple tasks. Yesterday I decided that I'd give it a more serious try and I made a simple console-application which would intarface with MySQL. I used `mysql.connector` module, and everythiing worked fine. Then I thought I could have given it a GUI, and I installed `Tkinter` since it was the most used on online tutorials. When I tried to run again my appicatio Python would tell me

`ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`

Which was quite strange since I used it till 10 minutes before, but ok, installing Tkinter may have messed something up, and I tried to reinstall `mysql.connector`.

I then remembered why I dind't really used Python: `pip` doesn't work for me. Everytime I try to install something with it, it gives me this error:

`Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-xg6au4u3/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-syqhbsu8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-xg6au4u3/mysql-connector`

Does anyone know how to solve this? Till now I've tried to:

- Use pip3
- Upgrade `wheel` and `pip`
- Use a `virtualenv` or option `--user` with `pip`
- Uninstall and reinstall Python

More information about the system I'm using:

- macOs Sierra 10.12.4
- Python2.7.13 (I also have python3.4.2)
- pip 9.0.1
- easy_install 36.0.1

Comment: Why did you install tkinter?.... it’s a built-in library......

Comment: Nope, when I tried it gave me `ImportError: No module named Tkinter`, so I looked up online and installed it through ActivePython.

Comment: It’s `tkinter` in python 3. `Tkinter` in python 2. Either way, they *are* pre-installed. Double check the error, is it *exactly* what you said?

Comment: Can you show us the install record? `/tmp/pip-syqhbsu8-record/install-record.txt`

Comment: It gives me `cat: /tmp/pip-syqhbsu8-record/install-record.txt: No such file or directory`.

I've also tried to run again `sudo pip install mysql-connector` and then `sudo cat /tmp/pip-syqhbsu8-record/install-record.txt`

Comment: Found a temporary solution: appratenely the error is due to `Protobuf` module, so I ran `pip install Protobuf`, and tried again, but nothing. Looked up on internet for this error and found a version of MySQL which doesn't need `Protobuf`: `pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4`

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029672/unable-to-find-protobuf-include-directory)