# How to store data in MySQL database via python

Tags: python, mysql

This is the script that I wrote so far. The first blocker that I find is that I am not being able to install MySQLdb package - Maybe I could use a different module?

```
import soundcloud
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame
import MySQLdb
client = 
soundcloud.Client(client_id='696b5ca70f5401cc46c9011c78831877')
userId = '110652450'
tracks = client.get('/users/'+userId+'/tracks')
data = []
for x in tracks:
    data.append({'Track_Name':x.title,'plays':str(x.playback_count)}) 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

database = MySQLdb.connect (host="127.0.0.1",user ="root",passwd="XXX",db="soundcloudstore")
cursor = database.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO Tracks (Track_Name, Plays) VALUES (%s,%s)"""

for x in df:
    Track_Name = df[['Track_Name']].value 
    Plays = df[['plays']].value 

    values = (Track_Name, Plays)
    cursor.execute(query, values)

cursor.close() 

database.commit()

database.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip see this to install mysql

Comment: Thanks Salmaan, but if I install brew install mysql-connector-c (which works) still doesn't allow me to use the module 'MySQLdb'. Would you recommend a different module perhaps?

Comment: did you import it using this import mysql.connector If it doesnt work, you can try the other ones.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you said but I also tried:
pip install mysql.connector and I got the message 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql.connector (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql.connector'

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html

Comment: Hi Eagle,
Thanks. I installed Mysqlconnector but when I ran the query I still see: No module named 'mysql'.
I even changed it to 
import mysql.connector and 
database = mysql.connector.connect

Answer (score 0):

Download the adapter here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html

Then you would use it as so:

```
import mysql.connector

data = []
for x in tracks:
    data.append((x.title, str(x.playback_count))) 

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='', password='',
                              host='',
                              database='')

cursor = conn.cursor()

q = """INSERT INTO Tracks (Track_Name, Plays) VALUES (%s,%s)"""

cursor.executemany(q, data)
```

This will save you from loading into a dataframe for no reason and `executemany` is optimized for inserts.

Comment: Hi Eagle,
Thanks. If I ran the script above I see the error 'invalid syntax' which I think is in the append section. Do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: I just edited you might have been using what I posted prior to the edit

Comment: Ah thanks! Now I see the 'old' error message: No module named 'mysql'
Any thoughts?

Comment: yea it seems mysql isnt in your path

Comment: what does it mean not being in my path? Do I need to install another module?

Comment: no it means that wherever you installed the `mysql` connector isn't in the same place where python is being read from. are you on a nix machine?

Comment: No, I am on a mac. but yes probably mysql connector it's not on the same place where python is being read from. Would you know how can I find the location from both to see the difference? I am not a technical person as you probably figured out already eheheh

Comment: it says: /Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaoPython/env/bin:/Users/joaopimenta/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: I think mysql connector is not installed in that location  but I don't know where it is. How would I find the location?

Comment: it probably isn't did you follow the instructions on the link I gave you. but to find everywhere mysql is, do this from your disk's root directory, `find . -name mysql -type d`

Comment: If I write that code I don't see anything. Yes I believe I followed the instructions from the link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ 
On mac it seems that there's no need to write any code in terminal to install id, just download the dmg

Comment: maybe I could get a more recent version. I got 2.1.7. If I go to the development releases I see version 8.0.5. Maybe?

Comment: Hey mate, got it working. I had to write this command inside my environment: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100757/can-not-get-mysql-connector-python-to-install-in-virtualenv 
Found it in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100757/can-not-get-mysql-connector-python-to-install-in-virtualenv

Thanks for your help and patience!