# Why is import of msql-connector failing even though it was successfully installed?

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to install `python-myconnector` using the instructions provided [**here**](https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/e4863e733d9d7e64d1f18757aca33f2e).

The installation succeeds:

```
(my_virtual_env)[my.username@my-machine ~]$ pip install mysql-connector
...
Successfully installed mysql-connector
```

However, then when I try to use it, importing the `mysql.connector` module fails. What?? Why???

```
(my_virtual_env)[my.username@my-machine ~]$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016, 22:14:00)


>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

[**Here**](https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/e4863e733d9d7e64d1f18757aca33f2e) is the full log of the installation and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

This worked for me in python 2.7.12 venv.

Also you can see a discussion on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100757/can-not-get-mysql-connector-python-to-install-in-virtualenv).